# How should I go about populating my accordian with data from mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table, accordion

I have a vertical accordion that I plan on using as a directory. I can hard-code all items in the directory and everything works fine, however, I want to populate everything with content from my mysql database. The methods I've tried for doing that have all been failures, because the structure of my accordion is:

```
 <aside id="directory">
    <div id="wrapper">
       <ul class="menu">
          <!--The main items are denoted by the li class="itemNumber"-->
          <li class="item1">General Partners <span>9th Floor</span>
             <ul>
                <!--items that will show when an element in the accordion is selected-->
                <li class="subitem1">
                   <table>
                      <tr>
                         <td>fName lName</td>
                         <td>email</td>
                         <td><span>ext. num</span></td>
                      </tr>
                   </table>
                </li>
                <li class="subitem2">
                   ...
                </li>
             </ul> 
          </li>
          ...
       </ul>
    </div>          
 </aside>
```

Like I said, when I hardcode entries in like that it works fine. My jQuery works as expected--everything's good. But when I insert the following PHP code after:

```
 <li class="subitem">
```

nothing works...which is kind of what I expected to happen but I'm not sure what else I can do. Anyway here's the PHP code:

```
 <?php
    //connect to the db server
    $connect = mysql_connect("###", "###", "###") //edited this line here
        or die("unable to connect to database");

    $mysql_select_db("###", $connect);
       or die("unable to connect to ### database");

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM staff_directory WHERE Department = 'General Partners'", $connect)
       or die("unable to run query");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
       $data1 = $row["LastName"];
       $data2 = $row["FirstName"];
       $data3 = $row["Email"];
       $data4 = $row["Ext"];

       echo "<tr>
               <td>".$data2 $data1."</td>
               <td>".$data3."</td>
               <td><span>".$data4."</span></td>
             </tr>";
    }
    mysql_close($connect);
 ?>
```

I insert this PHP code right after:

```
 <li class="subitem">
    <table>
       //Php code here
```

Knowing that this is obviously the wrong approach, how would you  handle this? Any help anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are there any errors? try to `print_r($row)` and see if it has all the data.

Comment: If I tried doing it that way, wouldn't I have to print the entire row as one value? I only ask because some of the items outputed (primarily the Ext entry which is why it's also enclosed in span tags) needs to be formatted differently and my css has pre-defined spacing between the name email and extension items in the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the top of the script, put all your database and query info etc.
Then put the following code in `.item1 ul`

```
 <?php $i=0; while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) { $i++; ?>
    <li class="subitem<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row["FirstName"] . $row["LastName"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row["Email"]; ?></td>
                <td><span><?php echo $row["Ext"]; ?></span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </li>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you. The styling is being ignored but I can work on that. Thanks again, that was a huge help.